# Wrap protocol: unhandled parameters (features.xml)

Tags: installation, bundle, apache-karaf

I created a features.xml according to [How to run Vaadin 7 applications in Karaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26247082)

So I got these lines:

```
<feature name="vaadin-common" version="7.6.8">
    <!-- preceding code -->
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.yahoo.platform.yui/yuicompressor/2.4.8$Bundle-SymbolicName=com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor&amp;Bundle-Version=2.4.8</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA$BundleSymbolicName=javax-validation-api&amp;Bundle-Version=1.0.0.GA</bundle>
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.7.7$BundleSymbolicName=com-google-appengine-api-1.0-sdk&amp;Bundle-Version=1.7.7</bundle>
    <!-- appending code -->
</feature>
```

When I do a `feature:install vaadin-common` everything installs, but only `yuicompressor` gets properly wrapped with

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor
Bundle-Version: 2.4.8
```

Bundle headers. But for the other two this doesn't apply:

```
karaf@root()>bundle:list
1335│ Active   │  80 │ 2.4.8         │ com-yahoo-platform-yui-yuicompressor
1336│ Active   │  80 │ 1.7.7         │ wrap_file__home_mine_.m2_repository_com_google_appengine_appengine-api-1.0-sdk_1.7.7_appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar_BundleSymbolicName_com.google.appengin
1337│ Active   │  80 │ 1.0.0.GA      │ wrap_file__home_mine_.m2_repository_javax_validation_validation-api_1.0.0.GA_validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar_BundleSymbolicName_javax.validation.validation-api
```

I changed `Bundle-SymbolicName` for `yuicompressor` to something different and the change didn't affect the headers. So wrap: isn't working at all.

When I type it directly (replacing `'&amp;'` with `'&'`):

```
karaf@root()>bundle:install 'wrap:mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA$BundleSymbolicName=javax-validation-api&Bundle-Version=1.0.0.GA'
Bundle ID: 420
karaf@root()>bundle:list
 ID │ State     │ Lvl │ Version  │ Name
420 │ Installed │  80 │ 1.0.0.GA │ javax-validation-api
```

All works fine...

I tried:

1. Replace `$BundleSymbolicName` with `$Bundle-SymbolicName`
2. Skip `Bundle-SymbolicName` / `Bundle-Version` and both together
3. Play around with `&amp;` and `&`
4. Wrap URI into `<![CDATA[]]>`

My assumptions is, that [Pax URL](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/Wrap+Protocol) does (or doesn't) do its magic here. It seems like the parameters aren't recognized at all. `bundle:list` always shows the same results.

I'm using karaf-4.1.1 which in turn sticks to OSGi-R6.

Ok I tried with karaf-4.0.7 and it works perfectly. Why not with version 4.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I pulled the plug: I deleted `${karaf.home}/data` and restarted karaf. It worked. Somewhat professional...

For reproduction I resetted and deployed a feature file:

```
<!-- features.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="javax-validation">
    <feature name="javax-validation" version="2">
        <!-- Bundle-SymbolicName=foo -->
        <bundle><![CDATA[wrap:mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA$Bundle-SymbolicName=foo]]></bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

And the bundle got installed successfully:

```
karaf@root()>feature:install javax-validation
karaf@root()>bundle:list
ID │ State     │ Lvl │ Version │ Name
59 │ Active    │  80 │ 0       │ foo
```

Since I deleted `${karaf.home}/data`, my guess was, that my problem was caused by some caching.

So I modified `features.xml` and deployed again:

```
<!-- features.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="javax-validation">
    <feature name="javax-validation" version="2">
        <!-- Bundle-SymbolicName=bar -->
        <bundle><![CDATA[wrap:mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA$Bundle-SymbolicName=bar]]></bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

And:

```
karaf@root()>feature:install javax-validation
karaf@root()>bundle:list
ID │ State     │ Lvl │ Version │ Name
60 │ Active    │  80 │ 0       │ foo
```

Ha! There it is! No change.

In the end I found a `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` inside `${karaf.home}/data/tmp` with this `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
    Bnd-LastModified: 1494796142136
    Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_20
    Built-By: hardy
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: foo
    Bundle-SymbolicName: foo
    Bundle-Version: 0
    Created-By: 1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation)
    Export-Package: tl.dr*
    Generated-By-Ops4j-Pax-From: wrap:file:/home/johndoe/.m2/repository/javax
     /validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar$Bundle-
     SymbolicName=foo
    Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven
    Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))"
    Tool: Bnd-2.3.0.201405100607
```

Cheers!